# Regex optional order of capturing group

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I have simple, but tricky question about regex (using in python), which i have did not find answer for anywhere here on google. Is there any "trick" how to make two capture groups in optional order? Let's say we have following:

```
.*abc.*
```

What i want is to match also this:

```
.*acb.*
```

I know i could use

```
.*abc|acb.*
```

but the problem is, that if we have something more complicated then abc, code is very long. Is not there any workaround to say e.g. "match last two capturing groups (or symbols, etc.) in any order?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get what is this in-any-order thing that would make the regex shorter. On the other hand, I can show you how to make this readable, even if you have tons of options.

```
import re
pattern = """
.*      # match from starting the line
(?:     # A non-capturing group starts so we can list lots of alternatives
abc|    # alternative 1
acb     # alternative 2
)       # end of alternatives
.*      # then match everything up to the end of the line
"""
re.search(pattern, 'qqabcqq', re.VERBOSE) # returns a match
re.search(pattern, 'qqacbqq', re.VERBOSE) # returns a match
re.search(pattern, 'qqaSDqq', re.VERBOSE) # does not return a match
```

So what did we just see here?

The `""" ... """` construct is a convenient way to define multiline strings in python.

Then the `re.VERBOSE` skips the whitespaces and comments. As [the manual says](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE):

> Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when in a character
>   class or when preceded by an unescaped backslash.  When a line contains a # that is not in a character class and is not preceded by an unescaped backslash, all characters from the leftmost such # through the end of the line are ignored.

This two things let you add structure and comments to your regex. [Here](http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/verbose.html) is another great example.

Answer (score 0):

With standard regular expressions you can define patterns without order. Example:

```
[cdgjow]
```

Of course *this example* refers to characters.

Alternative sequences must be specified using "`|`". Example:

```
abc|cba
```

**There is no way to express what you would like to express in classic regular expression syntax.** Regular expression syntax has no syntactic elements to express what you would like to express. It's lacking this feature. You have to rely on "manually" specifying your alternatives. It's not a limit of the automaton constructed from regular expressions but of the regular expression syntax itself.

That means: You will have to construct the regular expression you require by yourself with all variants possible. There are two ways how to do this:

- Do it manually. Take your time, be careful, built the correct regex manually.
- Do it programmatically. Write some code that generates the regex you require.

If you do it manually consider @TamasRev answer. (Thanks @TamasRev! Nice answer!) But if I were you I'd build the regex programmatically. (For things like that programming has been invented for anyway :-) )